# React Native - React Apollo - data prop undefined

Tags: react-native, amazon-dynamodb, react-apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I need to use data prop for refresher in scrollview in my component. So I need to call `data.refetch` in my `onRefresh` for Refresher. But I get data prop is undefined error.

Code:

```
class abc extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <ScrollView
            onRefresh={this.props.data.refetch} // undefined error
            refreshing={this.props.data.loading} // undefined erro    
          >
          .....
           </ScrollView>
        </View>
      );
    }
}

export default compose(
 ....,
 graphql(
   MyQuery,{
      .....
   }
 )
)(abc);
```

Why is my data prop is undefined ?

Comment: No. I didn't use a name. I only need to refresh data. Anyway I had figured it out by mapping props.data.refetch to a prop in my container. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself figured it out.

```
class abc extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      ....
      refetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      ....
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView>
          <RefreshControl
            onRefresh={this.props.refetchData}
            refreshing={this.props.refreshing}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(MyQuery, {
    props: props => ({
      refetchData: props.data.refetch,
      refreshing: props.data.networkStatus === 4,
    })
  }),
);
```

I mapped the refetch prop to a custom screen prop and called it from RefreshControl.